# Opencart JSON error

Tags: php, json, opencart, opencart2.x

I am having error in opencart which is like following

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

OK
```

> **Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   **/home/getyuva/public_html/shop/index.php** on line
>   **131****Notice**: Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   ControllerApiCustomer::$session has no effect in
>   **/home/getyuva/public_html/shop/catalog/controller/api/customer.php**
>   on line **7****Warning**: Attempt to modify property of
>   non-object in
>   **/home/getyuva/public_html/shop/catalog/controller/api/customer.php**
>   on line **7**{"error":{"warning":"Warning: You do not have
>   permission to access the API!"}}

Comment: try user access http://docs.opencart.com/system/users/user/ and admin/system/user/api try to adding IP